# Build expression from OData filter querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM app that builds a $filter url parameter which is generated using:

```
var dsContext = new DataServiceContext(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"));
var query = dsContext.CreateQuery<Product>("/api/products").Where(p => p.Category == "Cars");
```

So if I use "`query.ToString())`" I then get back a url like `?$filter=Category eq 'Cars'` and I use that to send to an external OData API that I do not have control of the code.

I now need to do the opposite of what I have done above and have a function that I can pass that url querystring to and it will return an `Expression` object equivalent to `Where(p => p.Category == "Cars")` so that I can use it in later in my Blazor app. All of the examples I have seen require access to an EdmModel or a context which I do not have as I am just calling an API and do not know any of that information. I do have a `products` class though so is there anyway to convert that filter querystring into an expression?